# python contact book while loop issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, while-loop

I want my code below to ask users to add contacts which i will save in a dictionary.

When user responds `N` to whether they want to add new contact, the loop is supposed to terminate. When `Y`, the loop must continue and when they enter something which is neither `N` nor `Y`, the question must keep repeating till they enter `Y` or `N`.

My code below does not return to beginning of function when i type yes

contactbook = {}

```
def addcontact():
    name = input("Enter the name of your new contact")
    number = int(input("Enter your phone contact"))
    contactbook[name] = number
    print("Contact book successfully updated with  :   ", contactbook.items())
    while True:
        qu = 'X'
        while qu not in 'YN':
            qu = input("Do you want to add a new contact? Y/N").upper()
        elif qu == 'N':
            break
```

After I reply Y to the question, I do not get the program to repeat

Comment: `upper` is a method. Use `qu.upper()`!

Comment: The condition for your `while` is `keepreading == True`. However, you are setting `keepadding` based on `qu`, not `keepreading`. Also, `while keepreading` is sufficient. You do not need to explicitly check for equality with `True`.

Comment: Also your outer while loop tests a variable `keepreading`, but then you're  setting `keepadding`...

Comment: Are you not getting `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'keepadding' referenced before assignment`?

Comment: @srig no I am not, i run it on spyder IDE

Comment: @EwuramaMinkaAkuoko, is it `keepreading` or `keepadding`?

Comment: @srig please check code update .. it was keepadding but i edited code now. kindly check

Comment: @EwuramaMinkaAkuoko, please don't edit your question and code while it is being answered.

Comment: Referring to your last edit: the `while` loop should be at the top and the `input` and contact book update should be in the body of the loop. `elif` is only valid within an `if` statement, not a `while` loop - change that to `if`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
contactbook = {}

def addcontact():
    keepadding = True

    while keepadding:
        name = input("Enter the name of your new contact: ")
        number = int(input("Enter your phone contact: "))
        contactbook[name] = number

        print("Contact book successfully updated with {}, {}".format(name, number))

        while True:
            qu = input("Do you want to add a new contact? Y/N ").upper()
            if qu in 'YN':
                break
            print("That's not a valid input. Try again.")

        keepadding = qu.upper() == 'Y'


addcontact()
```

Comment: this is great! but when i type dfd  in response to qu, I must be prompted to only tyoe either Y or N in reply, but in your code, it terminates when input is neither Y nor N

Comment: @EwuramaMinkaAkuoko, made some changes accordingly. Please try the function now.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are assigning to a variable named `keepadding`. The loop tests the value of a variable named `keepreading`. Because these variables are *different* the test will always be True and the loop will continue even if you enter `N`.

Update your code to initialise the variable at the top of the function and test the correct variable:

```
def addcontact():
    keepadding = True
    while keepadding:
        ....
```

---

**Updated following OP code change:**

Move the `while` loop to the top of the function so that the `input()` and contact book updates occur within the loop. Change `elif` to `if`. Here is a working version:

```
contactbook = {}

def addcontact():
    while True:
        name = input("Enter the name of your new contact")
        number = int(input("Enter your phone contact"))
        contactbook[name] = number
        print("Contact book successfully updated with  :   ", contactbook.items())
        qu = 'X'
        while qu not in 'YN':
            qu = input("Do you want to add a new contact? Y/N: ").upper()
        if qu == 'N':
            break
```

Comment: variables have been edited but loop is still not running as program is expected to

Comment: @EwuramaMinkaAkuoko: since you've changed the code in your question I no longer know what you are referring to. Perhaps you should not change the question but should instead add the new code as an update.

Comment: @EwuramaMinkaAkuoko: answer updated to correct your latest code. It should now work for you (it does for me).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that logic more cleanly by sth. like:

```
def addcontact():
    while True:   # no variable like keepadding needed
        name = ...
        # ...
        qu = 'X'
        while qu not in 'YN':
            qu = input("Do you want to add a new contact? Y/N").upper()
        if qu == 'N':  
            break
        # no need to specify the 'Y' case, the outer loop just continues
```

Comment: If qu == yes, it does not loop the program.. only the N condition is working here

Comment: if `qu == yes`then, by you own condition, you want to keep asking. If `qu == 'Y'` the outer while-loop continues as you want.

Comment: Please check update code now, it does not return to function when i type Y in response to qu

Comment: @EwuramaMinkaAkuoko The `while True` should wrap the entire function body! ANd you shouldn't change the code you try in your question, that will render given answers obsolete.